# Can I enter Thailand or Malaysia or Indonesia with a one-way-ticket?

Tags: air-travel, thailand, indonesia, malaysia, proof-of-onward-travel

I would like to fly from Chennai (India) to Thailand or Malaysia or Indonesia. Best with a one-way-ticket.  As I experienced a refusal to enter India with a one-way flight ticket, I would like to ask if these countries apply the same rule, will I be allowed to fly into Thailand or Malaysia or Indonesia ?

Comment: I am asking  whether I will be allowed to fly into Thailand or Malaysia or Indonesia (from Chennai).

Comment: I know that Indonesian immigration asks that..

Answer (score 1):

### Indonesia

Indonesia tends to change its unwritten rules every other day -__-

Basic rule is you need to show a continuation ticket.
Definition of "continuation ticket" depends who and when you ask. Sometime a ticket KL-Tokyo proves that you intend to leave Indonesia, sometime it doesn't.

If you have a letter from a sponsor (someone saying he takes responsibility for you to leave on time), you don't have to provide a continuation ticket. But last time I tried, they said I needed to provide an entry ticket :'(

### Malaysia

In theory you need a continuation ticket. I've been there dozen of time and they never asked me.

Comment: I was asked at check in (airline was China southern) in LAX to provide proof of onward travel on 2/1. I returned to Malaysia on 4/22 from Cambodia on Air Asia and had no such experience, and am coincidentally still here with no exit booked. I think it is highly airline and origin (distance) dependent.